# Eclipse View otion 'show' not displaying

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I need to select 'other' option from Eclipse view panel.But when I select Windod->show View->Other, I am not able to get 'other' option.I can see other options like 'XML', 'Terminal', 'Team' etc.But not this one: 'Other'.How to enable this option.I am using eclipse IDE Helios.Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.The reason is that the if there is any custom view, automatically the 'Other' option will be visible.Normally it is visible when a develop a plug in with a view.